# I don't understand mouse click events in javaFX

Tags: javafx, mouseclick-event

i have a question about javaFX, our code to change the color when clicking is:

bind if (rectangle.pressed) Color.RED    else Color.GREEN

Now we want the color, when clicking so that's red, to stay.
Can you guys help me?

Comment: See my answer below. Just remove the stroke part as it seems you don't require. Also it appears if you want it to stay red just remove the else Color.GREEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Code 1: hover and pressed Variables

The following code adds a yellow stroke to the square if the mouse hovers over the square. The fill color changes to red if the mouse button is pressed while hovering over the square.

```
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;

var r : Rectangle;
Scene {
   content: [
       r = Rectangle {
           x: 20 y: 20 width: 50  height: 50
           fill:   bind if (r.pressed) Color.RED    else Color.GREEN
           stroke: bind if (r.hover)   Color.YELLOW else null
           strokeWidth: 10
       }
   ]
}
```

or maybe what you need is:

```
onMouseClicked:function(e: MouseEvent)
            {
             if(circle.fill == Color.GREEN)
                circle.fill = Color.RED
             else
                circle.fill = Color.GREEN
            }
```